# Getting Image Details For Adding To DOCX

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am adding images to a DOCX files using the WordprocessingDocument method found here (Open XML) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430.aspx.

I can add images, but the sizing is not correct.

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
      {
           imagePart.FeedData(stream);
      }


return AddImageToBody(doc, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), fileName);

private static Drawing AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId, string filename)
    { 
       long imageWidthEMU = 1900000;
       long imageHeightEMU = 350000;

       double imageWidthInInches = imageWidthEMU / 914400.0;
       double imageHeightInInches = imageHeightEMU / 914400.0;

        new DW.Extent();

        //Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = imageWidthEMU, Cy = imageHeightEMU },
```

As you can see, you specify the sizes (length + width) manually. I am unable to get them dynamically. How can you get the right correct image size to pass to this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem solved here:
[Inserting Image into DocX using OpenXML and setting the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082980/inserting-image-into-docx-using-openxml-and-setting-the-size)

There is no way to solve it via instruction in the xml file. OOXML offers only `<a:fill>` and `<a:tile>` options.