# How to replace bookmark in Word document (docx) with an image using Open XML SDK?

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I need to take a template Word document with a set of bookmarks, and replace them with images (removing the bookmark itself). The examples of working with bookmarks I've seen are confusing and I'm not sure they apply to using an ImagePart, since it seems that things are different depending on content.

Could someone provide a straightforward example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below method `ReplaceBookmarksWithImage` to replace all the bookmarks with a given image. The word template file path and image file path are parameters. You can extend the code if you need different images for each bookmarks.

```
    private static void ReplaceBookmarksWithImage(string wordDocTempaltePath, string imageFilename)
    {
        WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordDocTempaltePath, true);

        // Read all bookmarks from the word doc
        foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
        {
            // insert the image
            InsertImageIntoBookmark(doc, bookmarkStart, imageFilename);

            // remove the bookmark
            bookmarkStart.Remove();
        }

        doc.Close();
    }

    public static void InsertImageIntoBookmark(WordprocessingDocument doc, BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string imageFilename)
    {
        // Remove anything present inside the bookmark
        OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();
        while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
        {
            OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
            elem.Remove();
            elem = nextElem;
        }

        // Create an imagepart
        var imagePart = AddImagePart(doc.MainDocumentPart, imageFilename);

        // insert the image part after the bookmark start
        AddImageToBody(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), bookmarkStart);
    }

    public static ImagePart AddImagePart(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string imageFilename)
    {
        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFilename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        return imagePart;
    }

    private static void AddImageToBody(string relationshipId, BookmarkStart bookmarkStart)
    {
        // Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
            new Drawing(
                new DW.Inline(
                    new DW.Extent()
                        {
                            Cx = 990000L,
                            Cy = 792000L
                        },
                    new DW.EffectExtent() { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                    new DW.DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Picture 1" },
                    new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                    new A.Graphic(
                        new A.GraphicData(
                            new PIC.Picture(
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                    new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                        {
                                            Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                            Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                        },
                                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                new PIC.BlipFill(
                                    new A.Blip(
                                        new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                            new A.BlipExtension()
                                                {
                                                    Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                }))
                                        {
                                            Embed
                                                =
                                                relationshipId,
                                            CompressionState
                                                =
                                                A
                                                .BlipCompressionValues
                                                .Print
                                        },
                                    new A.Stretch(new A.FillRectangle())),
                                new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                    new A.Transform2D(new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L }, new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                    new A.PresetGeometry(new A.AdjustValueList()) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })))
                            {
                                Uri =
                                    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                            }))
                    {
                        DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                        DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                        DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                        DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                        EditId = "50D07946"
                    });

        // add the image element to body, the element should be in a Run.
        bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(new Run(element), bookmarkStart);
    }
```

and here are the using statements

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
```

Comment: A couple of things: (1) the text previously inside the bookmark is still there afterwards; (2) the image is being resized;

Comment: The InsertImageIntoBookmark method takes care of removing the text inside the bookmark. Can you debug this code to verify that? For resizing the image, you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082980/inserting-image-into-docx-using-openxml-and-setting-the-size

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to put in the word bookmark, the image in memory stream instead of image file. In the marker I get an image with an "X".

```
public static ImagePart AddStreamPart(MainDocumentPart mainPart, Stream ImageSignature)
{
    ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
    imagePart.FeedData(ImageSignature);
    return imagePart;
}
```