# How to insert an image in a word document and maintain the original size using openxml

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, openxml

I tried do like this [Inserting Image into DocX using OpenXML and setting the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082980/inserting-image-into-docx-using-openxml-and-setting-the-size) but I not found the reference of "new BitmapImage"

I'am using framework .NET 4.5 on Visual Studio 2013 in ASP.NET MVC Application

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx)
Basically you have to use this:
Notice the ImagePartType

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
   imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
```