# Resize existing image in DocX using OpenXML sdk

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

Got template docx with image placeholder which replaced by correct picture.

```
private void SetImagePartData(ImagePart imagePart, byte[] data)
{
    if (imagePart != null)
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(imagePart.GetStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }
    }
}
```

but it preserves placeholder size. How to change it to actual image size? Byte array is aqquared from image on server, so size is known.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting Image into DocX using OpenXML and setting the size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082980/inserting-image-into-docx-using-openxml-and-setting-the-size)

Comment: i'm not inserting image. Just changing it and resizing

Comment: If you look at closer to code in the post (not only header) you will find answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean a content control with your placeholder you can use following code I once needed:

```
//Get SdtElement (can be a block, run... so I use the base class) with corresponding Tag
SdtElement block = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>()
  .FirstOrDefault(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>()?.Val == contentControlTag);

//Get First drawing Element and get the original sizes of placeholder SDT
//I use SDT placeholder size as maximum size to calculate picture size with correct ratios
Drawing sdtImage = block.Descendants<Drawing>().First();
double sdtWidth = sdtImage.Inline.Extent.Cx;
double sdtHeight = sdtImage.Inline.Extent.Cy;
double sdtRatio = sdtWidth / sdtHeight;

*Calculate final width/height of image*

//Resize picture placeholder
sdtImage.Inline.Extent.Cx = finalWidth;
sdtImage.Inline.Extent.Cy = finalHeight;

//Change width/height of picture shapeproperties Transform
//This will override above height/width until you manually drag image for example
sdtImage.Inline.Graphic.GraphicData
    .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture>()
    .ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx = finalWidth;
sdtImage.Inline.Graphic.GraphicData
    .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture>()
    .ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy = finalHeight;
```

But you can use it if you are just using an image in your word document too. You just need to locate the correct `Drawing` element which contains the reference to your imagepart. Then you can use the bottom part of the code to adjust the image size. It's important you adjust both the `Transform2D` x and y as well as the `Inline` x and y or the image size won't be changed.

Comment: Once I have the Drawing element located inside a Paragraph, how can I find the reference for it  in imagepart?